# Patterns for handling an event firing from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling

Suppose I have two threads.  On one thread, I'm performing a sequence of jobs.  On the other thread I'm waiting for user input to control those jobs (i.e., skip to the next job).  For example (pseudo-C#):

```
public class Worker {

    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    public Worker(Controller anotherThread) {
        anotherThread.SkipJobRequested += OnSkipJobRequested;
    }

    public DoWork() {
        foreach (Job job in Jobs) {
            // Do various work...
        }
    }

    // Event that fires on Controller thread
    public void OnSkipJobRequsted(Object sender, EventArgs args) {
        // Somehow skip to the next job
    }
}
```

I'm uncertain how I should handle skipping to the next job.  One possibility that occurs to me would be to have an instance variable (like, `IsSkipRequested`) that I set when a skip is requested, and check it at various junctures within `DoWork()`.

Do any other patterns exist that I could use to handle this event?

Comment: The best approach probably depends on what the Job is actually doing. Can it be terminated at any point? Should each job, once started, complete? Does a Job need to be cancelled gracefull if in progress? etc. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @RJLohan, a job does not need to complete once started - it can be terminated at any point without grace (though grace might be nice, it is not necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion would be (and you have mentioned this above) if you made `List<Jobs>` a `Queue<Jobs>`, and rather than DoWork performing a foreach maintained the current executing job in your object, you could simply dequeue each item when ready for processing.

The task parallel library allows you to specify a cancellation token (although you would probably have to pass this to your job execution code, and handle cancellation in there), which you can call RequestCancellation on when skip is pressed, and start the next job from the queue. Additionally, when firing off a new task you can specify an action to perform on completion, this would allow you to chain your tasks together into a sequential order and skip tasks when required. Below is an example without a cancellation token:

```
        _currentJob = Jobs.DeQueue();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {_currentJob.execute();}, 
        () => 
        {
            //On task completion logic
            ExecuteNextJobFromQueue();                              
        }
```

Be aware that this approach would probably work best if Job is performing multiple tasks and not one big blocking task as you would need to check for cancellation during job execution.

Answer (score 3):

Another pattern is the .Net class [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which seems like it should suit your purpose.  You could make *Job* a subclass of *BackgroundWorker*, and cycle through.  The difference is that *BackgroundWorker* doesn't know about your UI thread, only whether cancellation has been requested.

In this pattern the UI thread would call *CancelAsync*, then your *DoWork* method would check the *CancellationPending* at convenient intervals to decide whether or not to proceed.  You would call *RunWorkerAsync* for the next job inside the *RunWorkerCompleted* event handler.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks.  Does that provide any benefits beyond having an `IsSkipRequested` flag?  It sounds similar, but perhaps it is better on the virtue of being a standard recognizable pattern.

Comment: Also similar to creating a `Task` (.NET 4 TPL), and using `CancellationToken`, correct?

Comment: @Eric it also has an *IsBusy* property and a *ReportProgress* method which may be useful.  As far as *Task*, I haven't worked with that yet, but it seems pretty awesome.  If you're on .Net 4.5 this might be a good opportunity to play with the *await* keyword and all that new syntax.